# Command calls LuaLaTeX function, backslash in argument

Tags: luatex, directlua

I would like to create a command that simply prints what I give to it, but through Lua. Pointless for now, but I want to expand this to a more complex use-case. I've read a few answers around here, but can't quite figure it out. Simply put, if I give my command `hello \bfseries world` as an input, I'd like the output to show "hello **world**".

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{luacode}

\newcommand\mycmd[1]{%
 \directlua{tex.sprint("--->".."\luatexluaescapestring{#1}") }
}

\begin{document}

\mycmd{Hello world}

\mycmd{Hello \\world} % a bit surprised \\ works, why?

\mycmd{Hello \bfseries world} %

\end{document}
```

Comment: Number one LuaTeX gotcha: `"\luaescapestring{\unexpanded{#1}}"`

Comment: `\luastringN` is available when you work with `luacode`

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you! I was gotten... hah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your document loads the `luacode` package, you could employ its `\luastringN` macro -- the `N` stands for "no expansion" [of the argument before it gets passed to Lua] -- to get the job done. The point is that you need to prevent expansion of `\bfseries`.

I suppose that instead of `\luastringN{#1}`, you could also write `"\luatexluaescapestring{\unexpanded{#1}}"`. I trust you will agree that the former is easier -- both to remember and to write out.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\newcommand\mycmd[1]{\directlua{ tex.sprint ( "--->" .. \luastringN{#1} ) }}

\begin{document}
\mycmd{Hello world}

\mycmd{Hello \\world} % a bit surprised \\ works, why?

\mycmd{Hello {\bfseries world}}
\end{document}
```